# how to use multiple attributes with GNU style

Tags: clang, gnu

I have a naive question about using multiple attributes with GNU style.

The [specification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html) says:
An attribute specifier is of the form **attribute** ((attribute-list)). An attribute list is a possibly empty comma-separated sequence of attributes.

Now, suppose I want to annotate a function using two "**attribute**((annotate("xxx")))"

I can do it like that:

`void __attribute__((annotate("a"))) __attribute__((annotate("b"))) fff(){`}

But, it seems that I cannot do it like that:

```
void __attribute__(annotate("a"), annotate("b")) fff(){}
```

I was wondering how can I do it like the second form since it is more concise.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there - just add another pair of brackets:

```
void __attribute__((annotate("a"), annotate("b"))) fff(){}
//                ^                              ^
```